# Animate CC - Embedded video plays on SWF, not on HTML Wrapper

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, video

I am unable to get embedded video working in the HTML wrapper, whereas it works fine in the SWF file itself. The video plays instantly when opening the SWF, but when I open the HTML only the video player skin shows and no actual video, almost as if it can't find the video file.

Here is the exact process I went through to get to this point:

Starting from a blank ActionScript 3 document, I import a video and select the "Load external video with playback component" option. The video file is in the same directory as the project file, and the video file is referred to in FLVPlayback source as 'movie.flv'. From here I publish the project to SWF and also with a HTML wrapper. Upon opening the .SWF the video plays, however when I open the .HTML no video plays, although the video player skin shows up.

I have tried several different methods of getting this video to work, I have tried embedding the video solely with ActionScript, but the results are the same.

Is it possible to have the video load both in the .SWF and in the .HTML? The .SWF itself loads, but the video embedded in the .SWF does not. I have also tried using .mp4 files but have the same results. This is for a school project, so I am limited to using ActionScript, and the final project must be published to HTML/SWF/EXE.

Comment: Do you need video to be external file? You can import video to Library and play imported video. If not, you should download and install **Debug Flash Player** for your browser https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html so it will *probably* show the error which causes the video not to play.

Comment: @Organis The videos are quite long and have audio so I believed that using external files was the best way to do so. After downloading the debug flash player I see that I needed to add a trusted folder and now it works fine, thanks!

Comment: Yes, external videos are better as a coding practice. If trusted location was the problem, then you should try File > Publish Settings > SWF > Local Playback Security > Local with Filesystem

Comment: @Organis I appear to only have the options "Access local files only" and "Access network only" under Local Playback Security

Comment: "Access local files only" - I just don't remember how exactly it is spelled. With it you can *probably* remove global trusted location and it will still work fine.

Comment: @Organis unfortunately it has been set to that this entire time and it still requires the trusted location to load

Comment: Ugh. That hurts. Normally it should have no problem loading content from the same folder, but maybe FLVPlayBack component does something weird deep inside. Well, as long as there's a way to make it work...